# How to I make private class constants in Ruby

Tags: ruby, access-specifier, class-constants

In Ruby how does one create a private class constant?
(i.e one that is visible inside the class but not outside)

```
class Person
  SECRET='xxx' # How to make class private??

  def show_secret
    puts "Secret: #{SECRET}"
  end
end

Person.new.show_secret
puts Person::SECRET # I'd like this to fail
```

Comment: Of course, "private" in Ruby doesn't mean what it means in most languages. Ruby is not that big on hiding, so if you want to access something, you always can (but maybe not with the most obvious syntax). Ruby's `private` only says it can't be preceded by a dot (`.`) (which I guess is also a hint why it won't work on `::`)

Comment: Just in case. Ruby 1.9.3 has now private constants.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also change your constant into a class method:

```
def self.secret
  'xxx'
end

private_class_method :secret
```

This makes it accessible within all instances of the class, but not outside.

Comment: Perhaps a little meta-programming would make this more palatable.

Comment: I thought about it a little longer and then realized the above approach doesn't make the constant available to instance methods so I think I'll stick with @@var approach.

Comment: @DMisener: Ruby has a method for missing constants, if anyone wants meta-programming magic.

Comment: you can access this class method from your instances using `self.class.secret` in an instance method

Comment: @brad Instances can't call private class methods, even if the instance belongs to the class. The only way is to use `send` which defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: You can use private constant as well. Just as private as you with your methods/calls.

Comment: If constant is based on some values from database or http request, it's very bad idea to use a method which may be called in a loop. You can store it in the instance variable only once, but I'm not sure, constants are available for a reason.

Answer (score 177):

Starting on ruby 1.9.3, you have the `Module#private_constant` method, which seems to be exactly what you wanted:

```rb
class Person
  SECRET='xxx'.freeze
  private_constant :SECRET

  def show_secret
    puts "Secret: #{SECRET}"
  end
end

Person.new.show_secret
# => "Secret: xxx"

puts Person::SECRET
# NameError: private constant Person::SECRET referenced
```

Comment: This is so freaking awesome. I had no idea this was even a thing.

Comment: I don't see this method in the `Module` API until http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html  (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html)

Comment: @KrisRobison it appears to be some RDoc bug. Take a look at the comments section, on the end of the 1.9.3 page

Comment: @KrisRobison just to be sure: This answer is from 08/2012, and Ruby 2.0 went out on 02/2013.

Comment: Thanks @RenatoZannon. I had not scrolled down in the docs to read the comments.

Comment: This prevents accessing the constant from the outside but does not prevent from overwriting its value!!

Comment: @silverdr His sample code has .freeze already how can we overwritting its value?

Answer (score 12):

Instead of a constant you can use a @@class_variable, which is always private.

```
class Person
  @@secret='xxx' # How to make class private??

  def show_secret
    puts "Secret: #{@@secret}"
  end
end
Person.new.show_secret
puts Person::@@secret
# doesn't work
puts Person.class_variable_get(:@@secret)
# This does work, but there's always a way to circumvent privateness in ruby
```

Of course then ruby will do nothing to enforce the constantness of @@secret, but ruby does very little to enforce constantness to begin with, so...

Comment: Thanks...Seems obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

Well...

```
@@secret = 'xxx'.freeze
```

kind of works.

Answer (score 0):

You can just literally make it a private method in the first place ‍♂️

```rb
class Person
  def SECRET
    'xxx'
  end

  def show_secret
    puts SECRET
  end
end

Person::SECRET    # Error: No such constant
Person.SECRET     # Error: No such method
Person.new.SECRET # Error: Call private method
person.new.show_secret # prints "xxx"
```