# Hide some variables in ActiveSupport::Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a concern, but I want to limit what the Class that is getting it can see.  For example, I don't want anyone to use `PRIVATE_FOO` or `PRIVATE_BAR` separately, I just want them to use them together in `PUBLIC_FOOBAR`.  Is this possible?

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  ##This should not be visible in the class it is included in:
  PRIVATE_FOO = 'foo'
  PRIVATE_BAR = 'bar'

  
  ##This should be visible to the class it is included in:
  PUBLIC_FOOBAR = PRIVATE_FOO + PRIVATE_BAR

end

class MyClass < ApplicationRecord
  include MyConcern
  
  PRIVATE_FOO # NameError Exception
  PRIVATE_BAR # NameError Exception

  PUBLIC_FOOBAR # "foobar"

end
```

Comment: You can find your answer her https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873903/how-to-i-make-private-class-constants-in-ruby.

Comment: in `MyConcern` did you mean to write `PUBLIC_FOOBAR = PRIVATE_FOO + PRIVATE_BAR` ? b/c variables `foo` and `bar` are not defined.

Comment: indeed!  updated

Comment: @PrathameshVichare - I can still see @@PRIVATE_FOO from within MyClass, same with using private_constant.

Comment: @Ashbury there is nothing that is truly private in ruby. Marking something as "private" is more of a warning that this is an internal concern but it does not make it truly private. It's a bit like putting up a fence, it suggests you should stop here and even makes it more difficult to proceed but it certainly does not completely prevent access.

Comment: `@@PRIVATE_FOO` is not a constant. Its a class variable. Ruby will only treat an identifier as a constant if it starts with an uppercase letter which is not any of the sigils - `@`, `@@`, `$` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants in Ruby are always public so this is not possible.

If you want to limit the visibility you should just use local variables:

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  foo = 'foo'
  bar = 'bar'
  
  FOOBAR = foo + bar
end
```

Or instance variables:

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # these instance variables belong to the module itself
  @foo = 'foo'
  @bar = 'bar'
  
  FOOBAR = @foo + @bar
end
```

Or methods:

```
module MyConcern

  private

  def self.foo
    'foo'
  end

  def self.bar
    'bar'
  end

  FOOBAR = foo + bar
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ActiveSupport::Concern is a bit too liberal for your scenario. The following achieves what I think you're looking for. But it's definitely not very elegant!

```rb
module MyConcern
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      const_set(:PUBLIC_FOOBAR, ClassMethods::PRIVATE_FOO + ClassMethods::PRIVATE_BAR)
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    PRIVATE_FOO = "foo"
    PRIVATE_BAR = "bar"
  end

end

class MyClass
  include MyConcern

  def self.get
    PUBLIC_FOOBAR
  end

  def self.get_private
    PRIVATE_FOO
  end
end

MyClass.get #=> 'foobar'

MyClass.get_private #=> uninitialized constant MyClass::PRIVATE_FOO (NameError)
```

However there is still a way that `MyClass` can get the private constants, using `ClassMethods::PRIVATE_FOO`. Maybe you can live with that?